# Rewrite Rule for a specific project folder (WAMP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `WAMP` `vhost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName testProject
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/testproject/public
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/testproject/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

When I access the link `testproject` link I land on `testproject/home/`. The `testproject` folder has the following structure:

[image]

Inside the `.htaccess` from `profile-update` folder I am trying to apply a `RewriteRule`. Here is the code inside:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC, L]
```

I am trying to rewrite the `URL` from `testproject/profile-update/?id=1` to `testproject/profile-update/id/1`, but it does not seem to work.

I checked similar questions and tried, with no results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteRule ^/public/profile-update/id/([0-9]+)/?$ /public/profile-update/index.php?id=$1 [NC, L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(?:profile-update/)?id/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile-update/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Just loaded the URL: `http://testproject/profile-update/id/1` and got the response: `The requested URL /profile-update/id/1 was not found on this server.`